# Pyrogram awaited OverflowError: int too big to convert

Tags: python, pyrogram

So, when i try to

```py
await bot.get_messages(CHAT_ID, MESSAGE_ID)
```

i get `OverflowError: int too big to convert`.

Both CHAT_ID and MESSAGE_ID are `int`.
Any ideas?

## Expected

`await app.get_messages(CHAT_ID, MESSAGE_ID)` returns `types.Message`

Comment: Please include how you define the `CHAT_ID`.

Comment: One possible cause of this error is that the values of CHAT_ID and/or MESSAGE_ID are too large to be represented as 32-bit signed integers. You can check if this is the case by printing their values and verifying if they are within the range of a 32-bit signed integer (-2147483648 to 2147483647).

If the values of CHAT_ID and/or MESSAGE_ID are indeed too large, you may need to use a different method or library that can handle larger integer values.

Comment: @doneforaiur `CHAT_ID = -801109120`

Comment: Oops, forgot to ask the `MESSAGE_ID`. CHAT_ID seems fine.